# Deploy Nodejs on Heroku fails serving static files located in subfolders

Tags: node.js, heroku, express, static-files

I'm deploying a NodeJs application using Heroku. Everything works fine except a little issue serving static files.

I have the following configuration

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/htdocs'));
```

It works fine except when I try to serve static files located in sub folders.

> www.example.com/bar.js  // this serves the file /htdocs/bar.js
>
> www.example.com/foo/bar.js  // this can't find the file
>   /htdocs/foo/bar.js

I forgot to say that on my local environment everything works fine, might be something with heroku but I can't find the reason. Did someone had this problem before? Solutions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Finally I found the solution.

I solved that just adding the npm version in my package.json.

```
{
    "name": "bla",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "3.2.6"
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": "0.10.11",
        "npm": "1.2.25"
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Apparently, as explain in this question: [Heroku(Cedar) + Node + Express + Jade Client-side javascript files in subdirectory work locally with foreman+curl but not when pushed to Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10367600/herokucedar-node-express-jade-client-side-javascript-files-in-subdirecto), you can't use __dirname with Heroku.

The alternative seems to be:

> // At the top of your web.js
> process.env.PWD = process.cwd()
>
> // Then
> app.use(express.static(process.env.PWD + '/htdocs'));

Comment: Hey! I already found that and didn't worked... But I actually found the soultion right now!!! It was just my package.json, I forgot to put the npm version, I don't know why but this solves the whole thing. Thanks!

Comment: I would guess it's because Heroku need it in order to download the right version of NPM. And by default it should download a very old one. We don't know what should have happened then :)

Comment: I've added an npm version to package.json, AND did this solution. Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 9):

If none of these solutions worked, check [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45476027/877651).

> **Make sure that the sub directories of your directory are added to your Git repository.**

Comment: this worked for me. I was ignoring my /dist directory in .gitignore. I removed it and static file links worked as expected.

Comment: Same for me, now i know what .gitignores does :P

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem in my case by removing the public folder from the *.gitignore* file. I don't know what it was doing there.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for a while and had to revert to using /public (from /dist) as the static folder - works perfectly now

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a step in my build that was actually wiping out the `/public` folder, and then adding back in a bundle.js and bundle.css.

So on my local I didn't see it, but when it was deployed to Heroku the assets were missing.