# Getting express.js to show a public folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've recently built a quick one page app using express.js, and this is really my first js framework (actually, my first js project, so I'm really new to this). I've got a subscription to the new typography.com cloud fonts, and I'm having trouble locating the "fonts" folder that I place in the public folder. Is there a way I need to add the folder and specify a route?

Here's my app.js file:

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express'),
    routes = require('./routes'),
    user = require('./routes/user'),
    http = require('http'),
    path = require('path');

var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static('public'));

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/users', user.list);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

I haven't made any changes to the routes at all, so they are just default.

Comment: can you show your code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please use `express.static` setting:

```
app.use(express.static(process.cwd() + '/public'));
```

And place your `fonts` folder in that `public` folder.

Comment: I added that to my app.js, and also replaced the line app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))); (I tried both ways), but neither were able to locate the fonts folder in the public, or even if I put it in the stylesheets folder.

Comment: Do you use any proxying or accessing node process directly on port it listens?

Comment: (Sorry, I don't quite understand). All I've done is add web: node app.js to my Procfile, so it could host on heroku. Other than that, I modified the default template and stylesheet, nothing else.

Comment: Could you please share CSS where you load `@font-face`?
As well could you please share url and where you've uploaded locally fonts?

Comment: That's the problem, I'm not able to use @font-face yet. The site is [here](http://spencerhamm.com), but it's referencing the main css file from typography.com, and it's technically called in "development" mode. To put the fonts in production, I have to move them to a folder on my server, which I don't know how to reference haha.

Comment: Here you go: http://pastebin.com/0LMqETW1 you need to replace file.woff with appropriate file based on what files you can get from typography.com. This list of `@font-face` is based on list of `@font-face`'s in link that is for 'development'. As well place all files in `public/fonts/` and it should work.

Comment: I still can't even get the public/fonts folder to view locally :/

Comment: Please share the node.js code of how you are setting up express and `static`.

Comment: i updated the question with my file. Thanks for your help!! It's most likely a noob mistake, I really don't know what I'm doing with the JS frameworks, thought I would try something new.

Comment: Try changing this: `app.use(express.static('public'));` to this: `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`. I can see that the code is a bit messy, you might refactor it later :)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Heroku, you may want to look at this thread: [Deploy Nodejs on Heroku fails serving static files located in subfolders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17212624/deploy-nodejs-on-heroku-fails-serving-static-files-located-in-subfolders/17213574#comment24940832_17213574)

The guy explain that he struggled with "__dirname" until he specified the last version of NPM in his package.json:

```
"engines": {
    "node": "0.10.11",
    "npm": "1.2.25"
}
```

If that doesn't work, you might try:

```
// At the top of your web.js
process.env.PWD = process.cwd()

// Then
app.use(express.static(process.env.PWD + '/public'));
```

Instead of "__dirname"

Though, all that is probably useless if you already struggle localy.

Comment: man, I didn't declare that, but sadly I can't get it to work locally. It's almost at a point where I have to stop using node, or just use typekit instead :/

Comment: You are experiencing not a node problem. Could you put any file in /fonts/ dir, and navigate directly in browser to that file? If that working, then public static files working perfectly, and you having problem with the way you trying to reference them.