# Chat Server With NodeJS and Socket.io

Tags: node.js, sockets

I've Written This script for the server

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    server = require('http').createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(3000);

app.get('/' , function(req,res){
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.sockets.on('connection' , function(socket){
    socket.on('send message' , function(data){
        io.sockets.emit('new message' , data);
    });
});
```

And This Is The Chatting Page

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Chat Program</title>
<style>
#chat{
height:400px;
}
</style>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest-min.js"></script>
    <script src="/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        jQuery(function($){
            var socket = io.connect();
            var $messageform = $('#send-message');
            var $messagebox = $('#message');
            var $chat = $('#chat');

            $messageform.submit(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                socket.emit('send message' , $messagebox.val());
                $messagebox.val("");
            });

            socket.on('new message' , function(data){
                $chat.append(data + "<br/>");
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chat"></div>
    <form id="send-message">
        <input size="35" id="message"></input>
        <input type="submit"></input>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I Run The script from the console it runs well but when i write something in the chatting box nothing happen... I Don't Know Why But i think that the folder which i downloaded from "npm install socket.io-client" have a problem.

This Line ==> `<script src="/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/socket.io.js"></script>`I Think The Problem is here as the whole code is proper and right (I think)

hint : I'm Node.js beginner

Comment: is `node_modules` in your public folder? if not, your webpage will never get that file. symlink it into your public folder and you should be good

Comment: it's in the same folder of the script
here ==> http://i.imgur.com/Jgkxqj2.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You dont have express configured to serve the file. You have 2 options. You can:

1. configure express to serve that file explicitly

   add this to your app file:

   ```
   app.get('/socket.io.js' , function(req,res){
       res.sendfile(__dirname + '/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/socket.io.js');
   });
   ```

   and switch your html script to:

   ```html
   <script src="/socket.io.js"></script>
   ```
2. configure express to server any file in a directory (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17449475/getting-express-js-to-show-a-public-folder))

Comment: yep, looks like that should do it. you'll need to change your HTML too