# Subdirectories not being served with express.static in heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, express, static-files

I'm seeing some really odd behavior where some of my files are correctly being returned by my express/node server (using `express.static()`), but not files within subdirectories.  The frustrating thing is that it works fine using node or foreman locally, it just won't work on heroku. [This gist](https://gist.github.com/jeffthink/6927836) has the main files at play here, and my app structure looks like this:

```
-app
    - index.html
    - img/
        - base.png
        - sub/
            - sub.png
    - scripts
        - base.js
        - sub/
            - sub.js
    - css
        - base.css
        - sub/
            - sub.css
- server
    - app.js
```

The index.html, and base.* files all load fine, it's just the sub.* files that 404.  Seems bizarre that express.static would go 1 level deep, but not 2

I've tried a slew of different configurations, including this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17212624/deploy-nodejs-on-heroku-fails-serving-static-files-located-in-subfolders).  I have to be missing something simple.  Thanks for the help.

UPDATE:

When I console.log the following on server startup on heroku, I get:

- `path.join(__dirname, '../app')` = `/app`
- `path.join(__dirname, '/../app')` = `/app/app`
- `path.normalize(path.join(__dirname, '../app'))` = `/app/app`
- `path.join(process.cwd(), '../app')` = `/app/app`

Answer (score 3):

**Make sure that the sub directories of your directory are added to your Git repository.**

You can use `heroku run 'ls ~'` to help debug the issue (by observing the files on the dyno).

Putting the absolute path did not fix it for me. Your `.gitignore` may be excluding it.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your static dir to :

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/../app'), { maxAge: 86400000 }));
```

or

```
app.use(express.static(path.normalize(path.join(__dirname, '../app')), { maxAge: 86400000 }));
```

Comment: Normalizing paths worked for me too!

Answer (score 1):

add {{__dirname}}

`<link href="{{__dirname}}/stylesheets/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection"/>`

in your layout.hbs or layout.jde

Answer (score 0):

I've just had the same issue, and I've read all the different answers, some of which may have been important, but, in the end, this is the change I made after which the static content started getting served.

```
CALENDARSPATH = path.join(process.env.PWD, 'calendars');
```

...

```
-app.use(express.static(CALENDARSPATH, { maxAge: 86400000 }));
+app.use('/calendars', express.static(CALENDARSPATH, { maxAge: 86400000 }));
```