# Node.js app served on Heroku can't find static assets in subfolders

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, express

This question is very similar to the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17212624/deploy-nodejs-on-heroku-fails-serving-static-files-located-in-subfolders#answers-header), except that none of the answers seem to work for me.

I've deployed my node.js app to Heroku. I'm serving static assets like so:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Inside my `public` directory, I have a bunch of subfolders:

1. `javascripts`
2. `images`
3. `foundation`

All my static assets are being served correctly from `javascripts` and `images`, but all GET requests to assets within `foundation` are 404'd.

I've tried changing the way I serve files:

```
process.env.PWD = process.cwd()
app.use(express.static(process.env.PWD + '/public'));
```

And added version numbers to my `package.json`, but no assets within `foundation` are being served. Why is that one subfolder a problem? Does anyone have any fixes?

Thanks!

EDIT

I'm referencing the foundation folder like this:

```
<script src="/foundation/bower_components/foundation/modernizr/modernizr.js"></script>
```

That `src` mimics the exact directory structure...what could be going wrong?

Comment: Are the files inside other folders: images being served?

Comment: Yes. Everything is served except files within `Foundation`

Comment: how you are referencing *Foundation* folder in your html. Please drop here some code reference.

Comment: It's not because of the lowercase "f" in the html, is it?

Comment: Nope, that wasn't a problem :(