# Static files for Angular/Express app not showing up on heroku but working locally

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, heroku

I have all of the static files in a directory called 'public' which has an index.html file. However when deployed to Heroku the css and javascript files in the public directory are not there. I get 404 errors because they don't exist, yet the files are present in local and there is no error.

In my app.js I have

```
app.use( express.static( 'public' ) );
```

When I run heroku run bash the js/css files just aren't there. In addition to that I get [this error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Error:%20%5B$injector:nomod%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.5.7%2F$injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3Dapp%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.7%2Fangular.min.js:6:412%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.7%2Fangular.min.js:25:72%0A%20%20%20%20at%20b%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.7%2Fangular.min.js:24:115)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.7%2Fangular.min.js:24:358%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.7%2Fangular.min.js:39:374%0A%20%20%20%20at%20r%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.7%2Fangular.min.js:7:355)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.7%2Fangular.min.js:39:222)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20db%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.7%2Fangular.min.js:43:246)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20c%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.7%2Fangular.min.js:20:359)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Bc%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.7%2Fangular.min.js:21:163). I tried

```
process.env.PWD = process.cwd()
app.use(express.static(process.env.PWD + '/public'));
```

Because that was a solution I found to a similar error but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Are these files present when you created the website or are they added later through a database?

Comment: They're present when I created the website.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
app.use( express.static( __dirname + '/public' ) );
```

`__dirname` will resove to the directory your script is in. This will make sure you have a full path to your "public" directory.

Comment: I tried that and that didn't seem to change anything. I thought having an index.html file meant that specifying the default route was unnecessary. Thanks though!

Comment: Did you commit you JS and CSS files? Heroku will only copy files that are committed..

Comment: Check out the accepted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17212624/deploy-nodejs-on-heroku-fails-serving-static-files-located-in-subfolders). Could it really be an npm version issue...