# How can I redirect to static javascript app from subfolder in a Node.js app on Heroku?

Tags: javascript, node.js, .htaccess, firebase, heroku

I have a static javascript app built in React that I've deployed to firebase, and lives at `example.firebaseapp.com`.

I also have a Node app that serves my main application at `www.example.com` and is hosted on Heroku.

What I'm trying to figure out is, how do I have the user visit to my static javascript application when visiting a given subfolder, e.g. `www.example.com/app`?

Also, is there a way to do this where I'm not having to deal with CORS issues since they will essentially live on the same domain?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17212624/deploy-nodejs-on-heroku-fails-serving-static-files-located-in-subfolders

Comment: No, that's a bit different. I'm trying to serve an application from an entirely different domain and I'm not sure how to serve the content from that application. I've read some different things along the lines of using a reverse proxy but I'm not sure if that's the best way to go or not.

Comment: Ah, sorry, got it. I missed the different domain aspect. You may want to consider moving the static app to Heroku. I'd suspect that's simpler, more performant (particularly during static app updates), and more fault-tolerant than proxying/caching the Firebase app from Heroku or vice versa. I know that's not what you asked, but it could simplify things in the long run.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the suggestion. The reason I've gone with Firebase is because it allows me to quickly/easily deploy compiled static assets (html,css,js,images) to a public URL, without the need for integrating into another Node app, and then deploying that to another heroku instance. Maybe I'm thinking about this wrong though. Nice name btw :)

Comment: That was confusing to read, Will :) *Will* offers good advice. There isn't any way to achieve this without a reverse proxy that services requests from the `example.com` domain and passes them to `firebaseapp.com`. To improve performance, the reverse proxy could cache the content that it fetches on behalf of the client, but I have a feeling this is more complexity than warranted. Alternatively, we *could* assign a CNAME record to the subdomain `app.example.com` that maps to Firebase.

Comment: Thanks @CyRossignol, I think I'll go with your second suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use nginx on the server that serves the main application. by this way you will not have cors problem neither the user will feel that he's being served on different domain.

you can start with this nginx config:

```
location / {
  proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;
  proxy_pass         http://YOURTOMCATSERVER:{PORT};
}

location /blog {
  proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;
  proxy_pass         http://YOURBLOGSERVER:{PORT};
}
```